# Plotly not showing axis labels or title

Tags: python, plotly

I've got a Python project that displays a graph using `plotly`. This is my code:

```
def PlotData(data):
    trace1 = go.Scatter(
        y=PriceData,
        name="Prices",
        mode="lines+markers"
    )
    trace2 = go.Scatter(
        y=MarketData,
        name="Market Price",
        mode="lines+markers"
    )
    data = [trace1, trace2]
    layout = go.Layout(
        title='Plot Title',
        xaxis=dict(
            title='x Axis',
            titlefont=dict(
                family='Courier New, monospace',
                size=18,
                color='#7f7f7f'
            )
        ),
        yaxis=dict(
            title='y Axis',
            titlefont=dict(
                family='Courier New, monospace',
                size=18,
                color='#7f7f7f'
            )
        )
    )
    go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
    plotly.offline.plot(data)
```

The `layout` doesn't work as I get no titles or labels in the resultant graph. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are plotting `data` without any layout, not your `Figure` where you use your `layout`.

Try

```
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
plotly.offline.plot(fig)
```

and it should work as expected

Comment: you are the guy !, Thanks.. after days of wondering why, i found this answer to my oops moment!